# The requested URL "localhost/pusher/auth" was not found on this server

Tags: reactjs, laravel, pusher, laravel-8, pusher-js

i am trying to build a video chat web application using laravel for backend and reactjs for frontend. i tried to find the errors here, but i couldn't. please help me to fix my errors.

**Errors that are showing:**

1/ POST `http://localhost/pusher/auth 404 (Not Found)`

2/ Pusher :  : `["Error: Unable to retrieve auth string from auth endpoint - received status: 404 from /pusher/auth`. Clients must be authenticated to join private or presence channels. See: [https://pusher.com/docs/authenticating_users"]](https://pusher.com/docs/authenticating_users%22%5D)

**My Code from *"resources/js/components/App.js"***

```
setupPusher(){
    
    Pusher.logToConsole = true;
    this.pusher = new Pusher(APP_KEY,{
        authEndpoint: '/pusher/auth',
        cluster: 'ap2',
        auth:{
            params: this.user.id,
            headers:{
                'X-CSRF-Token': window.csrfToken
            }
        }
    });

    this.channel = this.pusher.subscribe('presence-video-channel');

    this.channel.bind(`clnt-signal-${this.user.id}`,(signal) => {
        let peer = this.peers[signal.userId];

        // if peer is not already exists, we got an incoming call
        if(peer == undefined){
            this.setState({otherUserId: signal.userId});
            peer = this.startPeer(signal.userId, false);
        } 
        peer.signal(signal.data);
    });
}
```

**My Code from "*routes/web.php"***

```
 Route::post('/pusher/auth', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'authenticate']);
```

**My Code from *"app/Http/Controllers/HomeController.php"***

```
public function authenticate(Request $request){
    
    $socketId = $request->socket_id;
    $channelName = $request->channel_name;

    $pusher = new Pusher('a384f250f86af1f16f98', 'd30d380941bdec2e4e55', '1147033', [
        'cluster' => 'ap2',
        'useTLS' => true
    ]);

    $presence_data = ['name' => auth()->user()->name];
    $key = $pusher->presence_auth($channelName, $socketId, auth()->id(), $presence_data);

    return response($key);
}
```

Comment: `authEndpoint: '/pusher/auth',` this works only if your front end and backend runs on the same domain. Since you are implementing front and back separately you need to specify the full URL like `http://localhost:8080/pusher/auth`(specify port only if you are using a port other than 80)